# Middleware except

Tags: laravel

I have a group of route that I apply auth Middleware.

How should I except the tournaments.show ????

I only found examples with $this->middleware syntax, but none with  Route::group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']],
function () {
  Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController', [
    'names' => [
      'index' => 'tournaments.index',
      'show' => 'tournaments.show',
      'create' => 'tournaments.create',
      'edit' => 'tournaments.edit',                                                       'store' => 'tournaments.store',                                                     'update' => 'tournaments.update'                                                  ],
  ]);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`except`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) the `show` route from the `resource()` as:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']],
    function () {
        Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController',
                [
                    'names' => 
                     ['index' => 'tournaments.index',
                    'create' => 'tournaments.create',
                    'edit' => 'tournaments.edit',
                    'store' => 'tournaments.store',
                    'update' => 'tournaments.update'
                    ],
                  'except' => ['show'],
                ]
            );
});
```

And then define it outside the group as:

```
Route::get('tournaments/{id}', 'TournamentController@show')->name('tournaments.show');
```